# Google Analytics Campaign names are showing partially or cut off?

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to google analytics so apologize in advance for this question...but in the campaigns using UTM codes, some of the campaign names are displaying cut off and in multiples and I am not sure why. They are being generated from MagnetMail using the subject of the email as the campaign name.

If the image isnt showing basically this is how the some are showing:

1. Compare Quick
2. Compare Quic
3. Compare Qui
4. Compare Qu

And so on, each with a few clicks. It should be "Compare QuickArtisan Contractor Indication from Multiple Carriers in minutes" which eventually one of the campaigns displayed does show. How can I eliminate all these other partial names and/or combine them with the appropriate one?

Comment: This is off topic and should be posted to Webmasters, as this question doesn't deal with coding.